# Setting up QGIS print composer options from Python console

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer

If I have a print composer called "ABC", I would like to "tell" its composer  that I would like to

1. update "Map 0" to simulate the "set to map canvas extent" button activation
2. update certain text labels
3. activate "export to image"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the topic of print output from pyQGIS: http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/composer.html (Note: master has `QgsComposition::loadFromTemplate` method, which 1.8 has not).

Basically, in 1.8, you have to create the composition (with map, labels, etc.) from scratch in code anyway. So no updates are needed.

Answer (score 6):

Just an update for this question given the QGIS 2 API is a bit better for these things.

Re your 1, if you want to update the maps in a composer, use code such as:

```
map_item = composition.getComposerItemById('map')
map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)
map_item.zoomToExtent(canvas.extent())
```

Re your 2, use:

```
composition.refreshItems()
```

Re your 3:- as Underdark suggested, there is example code to export to both images and PDF at the QGIS Python API cookbook:- http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html#output-to-a-raster-image

References:- http://kartoza.com/how-to-create-a-qgis-pdf-report-with-a-few-lines-of-python/