# Command-line tool for writing a print-composer to file?

Tags: qgis, command-line

I'm looking for a command-line tool, to write a previously generated
print-composer to an image-file. 
The following resources I already saw:

- Related questions ([1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54165/how-to-set-up-qgis-print-composer-options-from-the-python-console), [2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/programmatically-load-composer-from-template-and-generate-atlas-using-pyqgis))
- A [gist](https://gist.github.com/NathanW2/4029400)

Nevertheless, all them are not doing, what I'm intending. I'm looking for a tool which looks like

```
qgisPrintComposer --print-composer 'my-composer1' --output image.png project.qgs
```

A starting point is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michelk/qgis-tools/master/bin/qgisPrintComposer).