# How to display selected features in a map to exporte as PDF

Tags: python, pyqgis

I've already managed to select feature by ID in a layer and zoom to it using pyqgis. The canvas considered this changes but the map that I exported as PDF do not consider this changes, any idea to solve this problem. This is my code:

```
xpr = QgsExpression("\"ID_PARCELL\"=1440")
it = vlayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
ids = [i.id() for i in it] 
vlayer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
box = vlayer.boundingBoxOfSelected()
iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(box)
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas() ###
canvas.zoomToSelected(vlayer)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Comment: Not sure but perhaps this post might help: [How to set up QGIS print composer options from the python console?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54165/how-to-set-up-qgis-print-composer-options-from-the-python-console)