# How can i set layer polygon in center in QGIS using python?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, python-2.7

I am trying to set a fixed zoom level whenever I layer is shifting on  different polygon. I have coordinates for all the polygons , I need each polygon to be on center with certain zoom level so that programme can take printout of the layout automatically.

PS : For print functionality , I already have code. I have made print layout program but it's make image centered polygon images with zoom level.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *

mapRenderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
c = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
c.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)

x, y = 0, 0
w, h = c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight()
composerMap = QgsComposerMap(c, x,y,w,h)
print composerMap
c.addItem(composerMap)


item = QgsComposerScaleBar(c)
item.setStyle('Numeric') # optionally modify the style
item.setComposerMap(composerMap)
item.applyDefaultSize()
c.addItem(item)

dpi = c.printResolution()
print dpi
dpmm = dpi / 24.5
width = int(dpmm * c.paperWidth())
height = int(dpmm * c.paperHeight())

# create output image and initialize it
image = QImage(QSize(width, height), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
image.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmm * 100)
image.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmm * 100)
image.fill(0)

# render the composition
imagePainter = QPainter(image)
sourceArea = QRectF(0, 0, c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight())
targetArea = QRectF(0, 0, width, height)
c.render(imagePainter, targetArea, sourceArea)
imagePainter.end()

image.save("C:/example/Ashwin/out2223.png", "png")
```

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to set up QGIS print composer options from the python console?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54165/how-to-set-up-qgis-print-composer-options-from-the-python-console)